# Trouble with mod_rewrite and 2 parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use URL's on a website in the form www.x.com/cat/prod

First i would like to have www.x.com/cat/prod pass to www.x.com/index.php?cat=cat&prod=prod and i managed with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&prod=$2 [B,QSA,L]
```

Secondly i would like to have it so if someone accessed www.x.com/index.php?cat=cat&prod=pro it should get 301 redirected to www.x.com/cat/prod and i used this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&|\?)cat=(.*)&prod=(.*)($) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%2/%3? [R=301,L,NC]
```

The problem is it gives me www.x.com/cat&prod=prod instead of www.x.com/cat/prod, i tried a lot of things i found around here but i still can't manage to get it right.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You two steps go in circle, what is the point of that? Why would you want that second step? you redirect the client to a clean url (why?), but that request then will be rewritten again.

Comment: The second rule is working like a charm. I think you have both rules on same and no condition which is messing up

Comment: I redirect the client to a clean URL since i don't want the content to be available both at /cat/prod and index.php?cat=cat&prod=prod

Comment: @KailashYadav what condition should i have ?

Comment: @Debrian you should add the 2nd rule as first rule in your htaccess or apache. it will always redirect the user to SEo friendly url and it will work fine with both the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?cat=([^&]+)&prod=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1&prod=$2 [B,QSA,L]
```